# Close open resource in Scala which does not extend Autocloseable

Tags: scala

I am trying to determine a good way to close opened resource. I am using Micrometer and some resources (all coming from micrometer) that I have added in the binderList extends AutoCloseable and overrides close method but few of them do not.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer

```
class MetricConfiguration extends AutoCloseable{
  var binderList : List[MeterBinder]
  def initializePrometheusMetricsConfiguration(): Unit = {
     binderList = List (
      new JvmGcMetrics(),
      new JvmHeapPressureMetrics(),
      new JvmMemoryMetrics()
    )

    init(binderList)

  }
  private def init(binders: List[MeterBinder]): Unit = {
    Metrics.globalRegistry.config().
      meterFilter(new MeterFilter {
      override def map(id: Meter.Id): Meter.Id = {
        id.withName("hello" + id.getName)
      }
    })
    binders.foreach(b => b.bindTo(Metrics.globalRegistry))
  }
}
override def close(): Unit = ???
```

I am new to scala, I know I would have done in Java by extending Closeable and implementing the method

```
@Override
    public void close() {
        this.binderList.stream()
                .filter(b -> b instanceof AutoCloseable)
                .map(b -> (AutoCloseable) b)
                .forEach(Closeables::closeQuietly);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure to understand the question: are you asking how to translate your Java piece of code to Scala? Or are you asking how to close resources that do not implement `Autocloseable`?

Comment: How to close the resource that do not implement Autocloseable

Comment: Also, is extending Autocloseable the best way to close the resources?

Comment: If it's not autocloseable, you have to call manually close method of it exists (maybe it implements an interface?) or call the appropriate method for each instance.

Comment: Not familiar with Micrometer but I'm not sure there's anything to close actually..

Answer (score 1):

Your Java `close` method translates nicely to Scala:

```scala
binderList
  .collect { case b: AutoCloseable => b }
  .foreach(Closeables.closeQuietly)
```

Comment: the collect function here collects the one which are instances of AutoCloseable right?! I wanted something that would filter it out.

Comment: I only translated the Java code you wrote in your post.